# SSIS- retaining null values as null in the csv output file using script task

Tags: csv, ssis, script-task

I am using execute sql task to read sql queries and then script task to write the query results into csv files using the method mentioned in the following post on this site-

SSIS: Script task to write recordset to file
([SSIS: Script task to write recordset to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059747/ssis-script-task-to-write-recordset-to-file)).
In addition to this, what I require is 'null' populated in csv files wherever the query result is NULL. How to achieve this using script task???? What additional code do I have to write??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this but the answer is in `Persist()` within the foreeach data row loop:

```
       foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            // TODO: For string based fields, capture the max length
            IEnumerable<string> fields = (row.ItemArray).Select(field => field.ToString());

            file.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, fields));
        }
```

You have to test for db null in your lambda expression.  This should work though I have not tested:

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = (row.ItemArray).Select(field => ((field  == DBNull.Value) "NULL" : field.ToString()));
```